# C++ function that can take integer or float or double or any other castable to float

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to implement a Vector3 struct in C++. I am overloading the "*" operator for handling multiplication with the scalar values. So it will work like this:

```
v1 = Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
v2 = 2*v1;
v3 = 2.4f*v1;
v4 = 2.4*v1;
```

All 3 operations will return a Vector3 instance. However, I don't want to implement 3 functions for this purpose.

```
    Vector3 operator * (int& const val) {
       float _val = static_cast<float> (val);
       return Vector3(x * _val, y * _val, z * _val);
    }

   Vector3 operator * (double& const val) {
           float _val = static_cast<float> (val);
           return Vector3(x * _val, y * _val, z * _val);
   }
   
   Vector3 operator * (float& const val) {
               return Vector3(x * val, y * val, z * val);
       }
```

Is there a better way of doing this with one function?

Comment: Why are the parameters references?

Comment: For large values, const references are more efficient since they don't involve copying large amounts of data. However, for numerical values, the numbers themselves are the same size, if not smaller, than the actual reference, which means there's no point in take a const reference as an argument.

Comment: Just thinking about this, wouldn't a const ref be slower? An optimising compiler would pass values using registers (FP or int) so there's memory access, a const ref would require a memory access, the address is passed in the register. I know modern compilers are smart, but smart enough to pass a const ref by value in a register?

Comment: I am still pretty much a beginner in c++. I guess you are right that it is a mistake to pass the parameters with reference. It is both inefficient and harder to use.

Comment: Oops! I meant "(FP or int) so there's no memory access".

Comment: @Skizz the compilers could do such an optimization to a `static` function, but not to an `extern` one (because it could in principle be called from outside, and thus must obey the ABI). Also, not all ABIs pass arguments via registers: e.g. 32-bit x86 uses stack for this in default calling conventions on GCC and MSVC.

Comment: Just provide the `double` version, and pass by value.   That allows implicit conversions/promotions of `int` and `float` to double.   Passing references doesn't allow that, since references can't implicitly be converted between types (e.g. `int & const` to `double & const`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are casting all of the types to `float` again, you don't need that.

If you defined your function to accept a `float`, then passed an `int` or any convertible type, it would be cast to `float` automatically. The following code shows that

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Vector3
{
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z): x{x}, y{y}, z{z}{}
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3 operator*(float val)const{
        return Vector3{val * x,val * y,val * z};
    }
};

int main(){
    Vector3 v1{1,2,3};
    auto v2 = v1*2;
    std::cout << typeid(v2.x).name();
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/cG3jbY)

If you want to use the multiplication in reverse order

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Vector3
{
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z): x{x}, y{y}, z{z}{}
    float x, y, z;
};
Vector3 operator*(float val, const Vector3& v){
    return Vector3{val * v.x,val * v.y,val * v.z};
}

int main(){
    Vector3 v1{1,2,3};
    auto v2 = 2*v1;
    std::cout << typeid(v2.x).name();
}
```

I used public members for simplicity. u may want to use private ones with setters and getters.

Comment: thank you this is also working great! This much of syntax variation really confuses me as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use reference parameters and the `float` data type internally, and you wish to avoid compiler warnings about implicit conversions, then you can use a templated operator function (note also the modified position of the `const` qualifier):

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    Vector3 operator * (const T& val)
    {
        float mul = static_cast<float>(val); // Change this to any specific conversion/cast you want
        return Vector3(x * mul, y * mul, z * mul);
    }
```

You will also need to use a `Vector3` object as the *first* operand of the `*` operator:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Vector3 v1 = Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
//  Vector3 v2 = 2 * v1;
//  Vector3 v3 = 2.4f * v1; // These won't work!
//  Vector3 v4 = 2.4 * v1;
    Vector3 v2 = v1 * 2;
    Vector3 v3 = v1 * 2.4f; // But these will
    Vector3 v4 = v1 * 2.4;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If you want a 'commutative' operator (that is, one in which you could use the *scalar* operand in either position), then you can declare a `friend` operator that takes two arguments (the constant and a class reference):

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    friend Vector3 operator * (const T& val, const Vector3& vec)
    {
        float mul = static_cast<float>(val); // Change this to any specific conversion/cast you want
        return Vector3(vec.x * mul, vec.y * mul, vec.z * mul);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.  That this kind of operator overloading is not commutative will cause problems in case I want to implement cascade operations though :(

Answer (score 0):

As I see, it's enough to define/declare variant with `double` and it will work with floats and integers as well.

Here is compilable example (just test & demonstration):

```
class Vector3 {
public:
    Vector3(double x, double y, double z): x(x), y(y), z(z) { }

    Vector3 operator * (double val) {
        return Vector3(x * val,
                       y * val,
                       z * val);
    }

private:
    double x { 0 };
    double y { 0 };
    double z { 0 };
};


int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    float b = 2.1;
    double c = 3.5;

    Vector3 vec1(1, 2.1f, 3);
    Vector3 vec2(a, b, c);

    auto vec3 = vec1 * a;
    auto vec4 = vec1 * b;
    auto vec5 = vec1 * c;

    return 0;
}
```